How to use Nextjs Client Router cache when data mutation is required?
I'm using NextJs 14 with AppRouter and have a rather simple scenario with SSR app:

A server component fetches an array data from my backend and pass it as props to client component
Page is successfully loaded to user browser and hydrated
User decides to mutate (ex.: change status of 1 of array items) and navigates to edit page
After some mutations new data is sent to the backend and item status is changed
User click 'back' in the browser and next Client Router doesn't refetch data from the server to show array with already changed item status... it shows data that was already loaded in step 2.

Server component code:
'use server'
export default async function ServerComponent() {
    const data = await fetchServerData();
    return <ClientComponent arrayData={data}/>
}

Client component array display code:
'use client'
export function ClientComponent({arrayData}:Props) {
    return (
      <ul>
        {arrayData.map(({status,text}) => (<Link to="/edit">{status} - {text}</Link>))}
      </ul>)
}

Client component to edit single array item:
'use client'
export function EditClientComponent() {
    function onSave() {
      //make request to change item status
    }
    return <form onSubmit={onSave}>...</form>
}

In docs there is only 1 option to fully clean client router cache - to use router.refresh() for ex. as
'use client'
export function ClientComponent({arrayData}:Props) {
    const router = useRouter();
    useEffect(() => {
      router.refresh();
    },[])

    return (
      <ul>
        {arrayData.map(({status,text}) => (<Link to="/edit">{status} - {text}</Link>))}
      </ul>)
}

but that solution:

may cause blinking
client router cache invalidates data automatically in some period of time and that could force double data loading from server

